# Return when last event occurred in Dataframe by Group

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my data frame:

```
set.seed(1)
minimalsample <- data.frame(ID=rep(1:5, each= 20), round_number= rep(1:20, 5), event_occurred=rbinom(100, size=1, prob=0.2))
```

| ID | round_number B | event_occurred |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 1 | 6 | 1 |
| 1 | 7 | 1 |
| 1 | 8 | 0 |
| 1 | 9 | 0 |
| 1 | 10 | 0 |
| 1 | 11 | 0 |

I want a new column lagEventOccurred which tells me how many rounds ago the event has last occurred, i.e.

```
lagEventOccurred <- c(Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, 1,  2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

for the first few entries and so on (note that if the event occurred in the same round, it is not considered, I only want to look at previous rounds), all of this should be grouped by ID.

| ID | round_number B | event_occurred | lagEventOccurred |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | Inf |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | Inf |
| 1 | 3 | 0 | Inf |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | Inf |
| 1 | 5 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 6 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 8 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 9 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 10 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 11 | 0 | 4 |

I tried multiple things, including something like

```
minimalsample %>% dplyr::mutate(firststep = ifelse(event_occurred==1, round_number, Inf) )  %>%
  dplyr::mutate(secondstep = ifelse((lag(firststep) < round_number), lag(firststep), firststep )) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(thirdstep = ifelse((lag(firststep) < round_number), round_number- lag(firststep), round_number-firststep ))
```

but it seems that I would have to iterate over the "lag" procedure 20 times to get the desired results. I wonder if there is a function that does not return the lagged value of a vector, but returns how many lags ago a condition was satisfied.

Thank you for any ideas how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't think of a more straightforward method, but this works. I have assumed that if the beginning of each "ID" group is a sequence of zeros, it should be treated as Inf. Let me know if this is incorrect. Using `dplyr()` and `tidyr()`, the workflow is:

1. Create copy of "event_occurred" called "lagEventOccurred"
2. Within each "ID" group, create a new 'id' value for every event using `cumsum()`
3. Use `fill()` to define start and end of each event 'group'
4. Lag the "lagEventOccurred" column and use `seq_along()` to return lagged length since last event occurred

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(1)
minimalsample <- data.frame(ID=rep(1:5, each= 20), 
                            round_number= rep(1:20, 5), 
                            event_occurred=rbinom(100, size=1, prob=0.2))


minimalsample <- minimalsample %>%
  mutate(lagEventOccurred = ifelse(event_occurred == 0, NA, 1)) %>%
  group_by(ID, lagEventOccurred) %>%
  mutate(lagEventOccurred = cumsum(lagEventOccurred)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  fill(lagEventOccurred) %>%
  mutate(lagEventOccurred = lag(lagEventOccurred)) %>%
  group_by(ID, lagEventOccurred) %>%
  mutate(lagEventOccurred = ifelse(is.na(lagEventOccurred), 
                                   Inf, seq_along(lagEventOccurred))) %>%
  ungroup()


head(minimalsample, 10)
# A tibble: 10 × 4
     ID round_number event_occurred lagEventOccurred
  <int>        <int>          <int>            <dbl>
1     1            1              0              Inf
2     1            2              0              Inf
3     1            3              0              Inf
4     1            4              1              Inf
5     1            5              0                1
6     1            6              1                2
7     1            7              1                1
8     1            8              0                1
9     1            9              0                2
10    1           10              0                3

tail(minimalsample, 10)
# A tibble: 10 × 4
     ID round_number event_occurred lagEventOccurred
  <int>        <int>          <int>            <dbl>
1     5           11              0              Inf
2     5           12              0              Inf
3     5           13              0              Inf
4     5           14              1              Inf
5     5           15              0                1
6     5           16              0                2
7     5           17              0                3
8     5           18              0                4
9     5           19              1                5
10    5           20              0                1
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you so much for your help and your solution, Leroy Tyrone. Such a nice solution using fill, a function I had not been been aware of and a pretty elegant stepwise approach yielding the desired outcome.

Comment: @Zahra - The general approach in these cases is to first identify each subgroup, and then run calculations. This often involves a bit of 'to and fro', as was the case with converting 0 to NA to exploit the `fill()` function. However, the `tidyverse` is a truly miraculous place so there is probably a more succinct way to do achieve this solution. Either way, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution that involves creating a group ID for when each new event occurs, a consecutive ID to capture changes in that group ID, a row number for each consecutive ID, and finally an `if_else()` + `lag()` statement to get the desired result.

```
minimalsample %>%
    mutate(cum = cumsum(event_occurred),
           new_id = consecutive_id(cum), .by = ID) %>%
    mutate(row_id = row_number(), .by = c(ID, new_id)) %>%
    mutate(lagEventOccurred = if_else(cum == 0 | (cum == 1 & event_occurred == 1), 
                             NA_integer_, 
                             lag(row_id)), .by = ID) %>%
  select(ID, round_number, event_occurred, lagEventOccurred)
# A tibble: 100 x 4
      ID round_number event_occurred lagEventOccurred
   <int>        <int>          <int>            <int>
 1     1            1              0               NA
 2     1            2              0               NA
 3     1            3              0               NA
 4     1            4              1               NA
 5     1            5              0                1
 6     1            6              1                2
 7     1            7              1                1
 8     1            8              0                1
 9     1            9              0                2
10     1           10              0                3
# i 90 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```